# Apache Cordova load external URL or website inside div

Tags: android, jquery, cordova, mobile, webview

I am loading Website inside App using cordova.InAppBrowser.open('example.com', '_self', 'location=no,clearsessioncache=yes') and everything is works fine i.e it shows complete website mobile view inside the app, but now I am using some navigation inside **assets\www\index.html** file and when user will click on link the navaigation I want to load the website inside the div OR without losing the navigation.

```
function load_web(URL)
        {
            cordova.InAppBrowser.open(URL, '_self', 'location=no,clearsessioncache=yes');
        }
<a href="javascript:load_web('example1.com')" >Web 1</a>
<a href="javascript:load_web('example2.com')" >Web 2</a>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In other words, you want to show a non-fullscreen external site using Cordova's InAppBrowser. You can't do this, as it will always cover the entire app window. You have to use iframes for this, but this may or may not cause your app to be rejected by the store.

Notice that iframes and InAppBrowsers are becoming more and more restricted and eventually, Google and Apple could simply delete all apps using **iframes** and **InAppBrowsers** for the so-called *security concerns* paranoia. (and I wouldn't blame them, for the ill-use of iframes that we see everywhere)

Comment: Thank You andreszs! I already have tried iframes but faces the rejection issues in some apps. So instead of iframe in the app if I put the html on on remote server and there load the other inside the iframe. And in my app just load the remote URL(Note remote url  page have some custom html as well as it will load the other website through iframe). is there will be same chances of app rejection ? Or is there any other some other tricks to achieve this. Thaks

Comment: Was hoping to see more action on this question and maybe some tricks for this. If you want to run a site within a cordova app without iFrames, I wonder if you could load the resource via XHR and just put it in the innerHTML of a div or something like that - going to do some experimenting soon...

Comment: I know there are developments in ionic that put the emnu of options on the InAppBrowser but in a way that the app takes a more native aspect. But it is a shame that after Googling a lot I still did not find anyone who gave clues. I'm disappointed.