# Is it possible wrap a website in a cordova app, but keep the server session and adding a fixed bar menu in the bottom?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

Wrap a wordpress website in a cordova app in such a way that when we use the app on the device:

1) If We login in a form in wordpress we keep the session between pages.

2) Show a menu bar at the bottom of the screen in our app to link to specific pages of that external website while maintaining the session

3) Even if it could be that from the cordova app we could access the loaded code of those pages to inject content or hide sections of the DOM.

Is it possible to do any of this?

We have seen applications that do so and using ionic or cordova but we are not clear on how to structure such an application.

**I add mockup example for clarity:**

[image]

In a cordova app we need to show an external web (inappbrowser or add a second cordovawebview) (**gray area in the mockup**) but over this webview still show a local html menu (**red area with links in the mockup**).

This menu is not on the original loaded website and we would use it to navigate to specific sections of the loaded website. So every link in the red menu must send url to the webview in the gray area and load them.

Thak you very much for your help, Please, We have done projects in cordova but we are a bit lost on how to get this structure.

Comment: Se apps make it with iframe for website, but it will be laggy in this way, and some apps use this way https://youtu.be/FxkB_oiG3RI else if your app was static (html css jquery static files) then put them page copy and paste with corsova and build them to act 70% like android/ios app..

Comment: Thank you Mostafa. There are companies that use the cordova InAppBrowser plugin to load the external web without iframe. But my doubt is how they manage to add a fixed menu always visible on top the InAppBrowser. This menu have buttons that load different  pages form the web server

Comment: Give an example (screenshot) of an app since i didn't get what you mean by that

Answer (score 1):

In a test today we have managed to launch an InAppBrowser in Full Screen, from the CordovaWebView parent (index.html as usual in cordova / phonegap developments).

This InAppBrowser is the grey area in the mockup.

Even from the CordovaWebView and using javascript we tested and can inject javacript and css code that adds a menu into the external web that we loaded in the InAppBrowser. (We are using CSS position:fixed; for this added menu)

This menu is like the red area menu in the mockup, with the links.

All this is working but  every time we change the URL of the InAppBrowser the menu disappears and is reloaded in the onload giving a little native impression.

Is there a cordova component that allows us to superimpose on an InAppbrowser a menu created in html.

Or is there a way to load a second CordovaWebView that we can control and load only at the top of the device app view and and in the bottom of the app view still have the space to display the menu. Just like with iframes on the web.

Sorry my English, we are still fighting a bit with this and it is an important project that we are trying to get.

Comment: I found this old thread in which they asked how to do it. And still nobody revealed how to superimpose a navigation menu on an inappbrowser. I have seen that it can be achieved with ion-footer and ion-toolbar but nobody has revealed yet how https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50306068/apache-cordova-load-external-url-or-website-inside-div We are about to lose this project because we did not find information and doing it in native completely is impossible for us given the times